# Writing text area value to file in directory : Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, linux

I need a help with ajax... Basically I am trying to write my HTML "textarea" value to file on my linux directory path on button click. I don't know if this can be achieved with ajax.

I tried below but seems not to be working. I created a zero byte file into directory path also to check, also need file to be created also with ajax call like `theFileData.txt"`

```
var theFileData = $("#datatextarea").val(); // Value: "somevalue"

$("#saveDatatoDirPath").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/textareaData.txt',   // Directory Path on linux host where I need to append theFileData value into textareaData.txt file
        type: 'POST',
        data: theFileData,      // theFileData variable value
        dataType: 'text' 
        success: function(result) {
            alert('the data was successfully written to host directory');
        }
    });
});
```

I expect a line in my file should be variable value `$("#datatextarea").val()`

Comment: You can't post to  a `.txt` file. It is  a static resource. You need to send the data to a server endpoint that runs a programming language that interacts with the file

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed at the client-side, which means it cannot write HTML to file on the Linux server. You need to build a REST API to write a file.